# SQL uniqueidentifier is incompatible with float

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes

I am somehow stuck with this error message inside my litle query

Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 37
Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with float

I have already tried to set uniqueidentifier for the values which are uniqueidentifier in their tables

Or set the values in the Import to 0 to identify the Problem further, but I had no luck.

```
    USE [master];

    if OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.powerdeviation') is not null
    BEGIN
     DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.powerdeviation
    END


    DECLARE @factor decimal = '1,5' /*   delete VALUE in workflow */
    DECLARE @item nvarchar(256) = '450294'  /*delete Value in workflow */
    DECLARE @item2 nvarchar(256) = '450295' /*delete Value in workflow */


    CREATE TABLE tempdb.dbo.powerdeviation(
    DeviceName nvarchar(256),
    DeviceTypeName nvarchar(256),
    TableID varchar(50),
    SiteLocation varchar(50),
    SiteName varchar(50),
    DeviceID uniqueidentifier,
    DeviceSerial nvarchar(256),
    TableName nvarchar(256),
    Factor decimal,
    tPowerColumn varchar(50),
    tPower float,
    t2DeviceSerial varchar(50),
    t2DeviceID float,
    t2PowerColumn varchar(50),
    t2Power float,
    t2Powerdeviation float,
    SitePower float,
    SitePowerDeviation float,
    typePower float,
    typePowerDeviation float
    );

    With cteTurbine1 as
    (   SELECT D.Name as Devicename, DT.Name as Devicetypename, LD.ID as TableID, S.Location, S.Name AS LocationName, D.ID AS DeviceID, D.SerialNumber AS DeviceSerial, LD.Name AS TableName, LC.Name AS PowerColumn
FROM CompMainConfig.dbo.DeviceType DT
JOIN CompMainConfig.dbo.Device D ON DT.ID = D.DeviceTypeID
JOIN CompMainConfig.dbo.LogTableDefinition LD ON LD.ID = DT.LogTableID
JOIN CompMainConfig.dbo.Site S ON D.SiteID = S.ID
JOIN CompMainConfig.dbo.LogColumnDefinition LC ON LC.TableID = DT.LogTableID
JOIN CompMainConfig..Resource R ON LC.LocalizedNameID = R.ResourceID
WHERE D.SerialNumber = (@item) and R.CultureName = 'en' and LC.MeasureFamily = '1' and LC.MeasureType = '1'  and LC.OrdinalIndex = '0'
    ),
    cteTurbine2 as
    (   SELECT D.Name as Devicename, DT.Name as Devicetypename, LD.ID as TableID, S.Location, S.Name AS LocationName, D.ID AS DeviceID, D.SerialNumber AS DeviceSerial, LD.Name AS TableName, LC.Name AS PowerColumn
FROM CompMainConfig.dbo.Device D
JOIN CompMainConfig.dbo.DeviceType DT ON D.DeviceTypeID = DT.ID 
JOIN CompMainConfig.dbo.LogTableDefinition LD ON LD.ID = DT.LogTableID
JOIN CompMainConfig.dbo.Site S ON D.SiteID = S.ID
JOIN CompMainConfig.dbo.LogColumnDefinition LC ON LC.TableID = DT.LogTableID
JOIN CompMainConfig..Resource R ON LC.LocalizedNameID = R.ResourceID
WHERE D.SerialNumber = (@item) and R.CultureName = 'en' and LC.MeasureFamily = '1' and LC.MeasureType = '1'  and LC.OrdinalIndex = '0'
    )

    INSERT INTO tempdb.dbo.powerdeviation
    SELECT cteTurbine1.Devicename, cteTurbine1.Devicetypename, cteTurbine1.TableID,         cteTurbine1.Location, cteTurbine1.LocationName, cteTurbine1.DeviceID, cteTurbine1.DeviceSerial, cteTurbine1.TableName, @factor, cteTurbine1.PowerColumn,0, cteturbine2.DeviceSerial ,cteturbine2.DeviceID, cteTurbine2.PowerColumn, 0,0,0,0,0,0
    FROM cteturbine1, cteturbine2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

Option 1: In your table definition, change Device_ID column as 
    DeviceID uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWID()
With this you don't have to specify the Device_ID value during insert. It will automatically use the NEWID() function and generates a new GUID.

Option 2: During your data insertion, you can call like below to get new GUID for your Device_ID.

```
INSERT INTO <table> VALUES (....., NEWID() as Device_ID....)
```